# Java: The right way to make a scanner

Tags: java, console, console-input

*First I'm a noob to Java so don't be mad at me if I'm acting stupid - Thanks.*

As I said I'm trying to learn Java. Right now I'm trying to learn the right scanner for [this mini-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292329/java-code-aint-working-the-right-way/21292799?noredirect=1#21292799), but I'm getting confused because people tell me to do it in two different ways. I just wan't to know which one to use and where I can use the other one.

**First Example:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

**Second Example:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = input.nextLine();
```

Please tell me how to make the " right " scanner for my mini-game and explain when I should use the other one.

If you know which one to use, another way to create a scanner for this or just wanna share the scanners and how to use them - then please add it as an answer.

Comment: In both examples you are making only one scanner and to the same stream (line 1).. In the second case you are just Using the scanner to read a line from the console and store it in a String variable (line 2)... As for your second question, you can use the same scanner as long as you want data from the same stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

This is calling a scanner and telling that it should be used in the console "System.in".

1. `String userInput = input.nextLine();`
   This line is taking the value u inserted in the console and saving in a variable named "userInput"
2. You can add this `System.out.println("the inserted value is : " + userInput);`

And it will print in the console the value you inserted

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, both of your examples are same as far as creating a Scanner object is concerned. Only difference is that second example is also storing the nextLine of input into a String variable called userInput.

Look here to understand Scanner class better:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html